# package:analyzer When the parameter type is Function type , type.element is getting 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-analyzer

I am using package:analyzer to do custom static analysis.

when I have dart code like below :

```
class MyType{

    final void Function(MyItemType) callback ;
}
```

When I try to access the `element` of the callback type : I am getting `null`

That is :

`parameterElement.type.element` evaluates to be `null` .
Therefore I cannot get the `source` file of the Types involved in the Function to import those source files.

This issue happens only when I use a `Function` type that is anything other than just `Function()`.

`parameterElement` is of Type ParameterElement from `analyser` package.

My requirement is that I want to import all the files that contain the Types involved in the Function. In my example code shown above , I wish to import the file that contains the `MyItemType` class.

Also if the return type of the function was some other Type other than `void` , I want to import the corresponding source file.

Comment: What are `parameterElement`, `element`, and `source`? Are they members of some class you haven't provided code for?

Comment: Ahh, you're using `package:analyzer` to do custom static analysis of that code; you're not *running* `dartanalyzer`.  Your question would be clearer if it explained that at the beginning.